# How to resize a fixed window in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, window, popups

While using TortoisSVN, I got an error message, but I cannot see the relavant path, because the window is fixed. This means I can't resize the window.

[image]

Is there some tool I can use to invest it and manipulate its size? I've come across this problem with another application and would really like a general solution.

Comment: Do you know what TortoiseSVN is trying to open? Is it keeping an error log?

Comment: Try this https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11799/turn-non-resizeable-windows-into-rezieable-windows/

Comment: You can try to mark the URL with the mouse and copy it to the clipboard (CTRL+C). Sometimes TortoiseSVN uses editors instead of pure labels.

Comment: @IQV Forgot to mention, it's not possible to mark anything in the window.

Comment: @RamonRobben I tried the program on your suggestion. It does add a resize arrow on the edges of the window, but can't actually resize it.

Comment: @oddRaven Yea it probably only does this for actual fixed windows by Microsoft. This is a message box or something.

Answer (score -1):

**ResizeEnable**

"Even if you have a big monitor screen but using a graphics card that doesn’t allow you to set a very high resolution, you will end up everything looking very big. It is annoying because all the window dialog boxes seems so big and taking up all the spaces on your desktop. It would be even worse if the program or dialog boxes doesn’t allow you to resize and it has its own fixed size."

https://alternativeto.net/software/resizeenable/