# Resizing unresizable/fixed windows in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

The Network Connection windows in Windows 10, such as:

[image: network-connection-windows]

... are typically not resizable (and I wonder why, really? Who thought that it would be a good idea to keep these windows fixed size, while the rest of the OS allows for resizeable windows - and why?)

Note that the above windows is possibly "special", since the screenshot program I use "Greenshot" can typically list all open windows in Windows, to allow for screenshotting individual windows from a menu - but it does not list this window!

I'd like to take a screenshot of this, except where all settings are visible, and therefore I'd like to resize this window.

[How to resize a fixed window in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1193467/how-to-resize-a-fixed-window-in-windows-10) recommends http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/ResizeEnable/index.html - and I tried it, but it seems to do nothing.

So, is there any way to resize these kinds of fixed windows? Doesn't have to be GUI, I could live with a cmd or powershell script ...

Comment: Does one of the following work for you? [5 Tools to Resize an Unresizable Window or Set to a Defined Size • Raymond.CC](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-resize-an-unresizable-window-or-dialog-box/)

Comment: Agreed, dumb design

Answer (score 0):

> Who thought that it would be a good idea to keep these windows fixed size, while the rest of the OS allows for resizeable windows - and why?)

"Fixed size" is the *default* state. Resizeability has to be added.

This dialog (which dates back to Windows 95) was built using purely the standard Windows UI toolkit, which never had a "layout manager" that would allow the programmer to just say "widget X sticks to the bottom" or "widget Y stretches to fill this space" – all [dialog layouts](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/dialogs.html) were defined using exact positioning of each widget: 100 units wide, 200 units tall, etc.

(Even the MFC toolkit, which is built on top of standard Windows widgets with convenience features added, only got generic dynamic layout support [in 2015](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/mfc-dynamic-dialog-layout/), and I'm not entirely sure whether a "core OS" dialog would have been allowed to use MFC anyway.)

So if the window were to be made resizable, it would be each programmer's job to handle window resize events and recalculate every position – with code tailored to each specific layout – so it was only done for windows that are actually important.

If you ever saw a non-English version of Windows with translated messages overlapping or getting cut off because they're longer than their English originals, that's why.

Overall, this may be one of the reasons why Windows is moving all of "Control Panel" to the XAML-based Settings app – as one big selling point of XAML *is* to have built-in support for dynamic layouts, to some extent at least.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these dialogs were programmed a long time ago when screens
were small, so the dialogs didn't need to be large in order to take
up a considerable part of the screen.

The programmers that created the dialogs just didn't set them up with
the attribute of being resizable, although Windows can make most of
them work correctly with just this one attribute flipped.

A freeware that does that for you is
[ResizeEnable](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/ResizeEnable/index.html).
Download the Zip file, unpack and run the program as Administrator.
Now all windows and dialogs become resizable (although not all of them
would work differently when resized).

Here is for example your dialog resized :

[image]